# Is it a good idea to use hidden inputs in email?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I want to connect the content of an email message with an object in my software. For example with a comment. When the user replies to a comment using email the content of the message should appear also in the system as a comment. The only way I can think about to accomplish this is to use hidden inputs in HTML formatted email and place there the ID of the comment. 
The behavior is similar to google groups where you can reply with email.

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom headers to achieve what you want.

[VB example](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.3.4.aspx)

Look it up in google to find more information.